# Aligning columns by removing empty columns in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a table of which the columns do not align since some rows contain random empty cells. I have tried the following below but it does not work. The table is supposed to have four columns. Is someone able to help me out?

```py
s = '<TABLE CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=0 WIDTH=672><TR><TD WIDTH="52%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" HEIGHT=19><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=1><P>(THOUSANDS OF DOLLARS)</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="16%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" COLSPAN=2 HEIGHT=19><U><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE Bold" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="CENTER">2008</U></FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="16%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" COLSPAN=2 HEIGHT=19><U><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="CENTER">2007</U></FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="16%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" COLSPAN=2 HEIGHT=19><U><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="CENTER">2006</U></FONT></TD></TR><TR><TD WIDTH="52%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P>Statutory Federal income tax provision</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE Bold" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="RIGHT">$     969</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><P></P></TD><TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="RIGHT">$  3,278</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><P></P></TD><TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="RIGHT">$  1,521</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><P></P></TD></TR></TABLE>'
soup=bs(s, "lxml")
table = soup.find_all('table')
row_data = []
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td'):
        if '(' in str(column):
            column.decompose()
            row_data.append(cols)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Can you post valid code? `cols = row.find_all('td'):` is a Syntax error. And what is `column.decompose()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the text of the cell is empty then decompose.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

s = '<TABLE CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=0 WIDTH=672><TR><TD WIDTH="52%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" HEIGHT=19><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=1><P>(THOUSANDS OF DOLLARS)</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="16%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" COLSPAN=2 HEIGHT=19><U><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE Bold" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="CENTER">2008</U></FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="16%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" COLSPAN=2 HEIGHT=19><U><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="CENTER">2007</U></FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="16%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" COLSPAN=2 HEIGHT=19><U><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="CENTER">2006</U></FONT></TD></TR><TR><TD WIDTH="52%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P>Statutory Federal income tax provision</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE Bold" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="RIGHT">$     969</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><P></P></TD><TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="RIGHT">$  3,278</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><P></P></TD><TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="RIGHT">$  1,521</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><P></P></TD></TR></TABLE>'
soup=bs(s, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table')
row_data = []
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
  for cell in row.find_all('td'):
      if cell.text=='':
          cell.decompose()
print(soup)
```

---

Here you can check all four columns data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

s = '<TABLE CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=0 WIDTH=672><TR><TD WIDTH="52%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" HEIGHT=19><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=1><P>(THOUSANDS OF DOLLARS)</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="16%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" COLSPAN=2 HEIGHT=19><U><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE Bold" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="CENTER">2008</U></FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="16%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" COLSPAN=2 HEIGHT=19><U><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="CENTER">2007</U></FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="16%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" COLSPAN=2 HEIGHT=19><U><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="CENTER">2006</U></FONT></TD></TR><TR><TD WIDTH="52%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P>Statutory Federal income tax provision</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE Bold" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="RIGHT">$     969</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><P></P></TD><TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="RIGHT">$  3,278</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><P></P></TD><TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="RIGHT">$  1,521</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><P></P></TD></TR></TABLE>'
soup=bs(s, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table')
row_data = []
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
  for cell in row.find_all('td'):
      if cell.text=='':
          cell.decompose()
print(soup)

final_data=[]
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
  for cell in row.find_all('td'):
      final_data.append(cell.text)
print(final_data)
```

**Output**:

```
['(THOUSANDS OF DOLLARS)', '2008', '2007', '2006', 'Statutory Federal income tax provision', '$     969', '$  3,278', '$  1,521']
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ever is see `<table>` tags, I just go with Pandas `.read_html()` and manipulate the dataframe. Pandas actually uses beautifulsoup under the hood.

So, get the table with pandas. Then drop the columns with any nulls:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

s = '<TABLE CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=0 WIDTH=672><TR><TD WIDTH="52%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" HEIGHT=19><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=1><P>(THOUSANDS OF DOLLARS)</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="16%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" COLSPAN=2 HEIGHT=19><U><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE Bold" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="CENTER">2008</U></FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="16%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" COLSPAN=2 HEIGHT=19><U><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="CENTER">2007</U></FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="16%" VALIGN="BOTTOM" COLSPAN=2 HEIGHT=19><U><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="CENTER">2006</U></FONT></TD></TR><TR><TD WIDTH="52%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P>Statutory Federal income tax provision</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE Bold" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="RIGHT">$     969</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><P></P></TD><TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="RIGHT">$  3,278</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><P></P></TD><TD WIDTH="12%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><FONT FACE="Akzidenz Grotesk BE" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="RIGHT">$  1,521</FONT></TD><TD WIDTH="4%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=15><P></P></TD></TR></TABLE>'

table = pd.read_html(s)[0]
table = table.dropna(axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
                                        0      1        3        5
0                  (THOUSANDS OF DOLLARS)   2008     2007     2006
1  Statutory Federal income tax provision  $ 969  $ 3,278  $ 1,521
```

You could also change the column names and etc.:

```
table.columns = table.iloc[0]
table = table[1:]
```